# Finding data transfer rates on individual TCP/IP connections

Tags: linux, networking

In a application that has multiple TCP/IP connections with other applications on a Linux system how can I find the amount of data transferred between individual connections.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `iptraf` command.  You can navigate to:

> `Statistical breakdowns/By TCP/UDP port`

You may need to install the package for `iptraf` using your package manager if the command does not exist on your system.  On a Redhat system you could do the following:

> `yum install iptraf`

You must also be root to use this command since it lives in `sbin`.